# Can Reformed Slavic Pagans Request a Great Holy War?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I'm new to the game, playing as Poland.  I have reformed the Slavic (pagan) faith.  The head of the religion (who is my vassal) has called a Great Holy War on their own already.  I'm wondering if it's possible to request one?  The targets he seems to pick are not appealing...

More concretely:

(1) Is it possible to request a Great Holy War as a reformed Slavic pagan?

(2) If so, how do I do it?

(3) [somewhat unrelated] Where can I check when the last Great Holy War was called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [wiki](http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Crusades,_jihads_and_great_holy_wars#Requesting_a_crusade), they only mention Crusade being requested, implying that only Christians can request them.

Something that may interest you is the Crusade Target Weight table, showing which kingdom are likely to be targeted by an AI head of religion. Kingdoms at 0 will never be the target of a Great Holy War

Comment: From that same wiki page, it notes that the Jewish Great Holy War ONLY fires by way of requests, so that's not it.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I did not read carefully enough.

Comment: Isn't there a 'Request Invasion' diplomacy action? What does it take to trigger that?